# SSRS Goto URL decoding and encoding

Tags: url, reporting-services, character, goto

I am facing problem when passing value for url through data field.

I am passing value in goto url like this

```
="javascript:void(window.open('file:" &Fields!url.Value &"','_blank'))"

url value = /servername/foldername/FormuláriodeCalibração.xls
```

After report deployed and opened in internet explorer and clicked on the url. It is changing the url like this

> /servername/foldername/FormulÃ¡riodeCalibraÃ§Ã£o.xls

because of which I am unable to open the file.

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

Finally we come up with a solution of replacing non ASCII characters of Portuguese with HTML ASCII Codes.

For e.g. this is the actual file name of the attachment

TE-5180FormuláriodeCalibração(modelo)1271440308393(2)1338379011084.xls

We replaced the Portuguese characters with HTML ASCII Codes.

TE-5180FormuláriodeCalibração(modelo)1271440308393(2)1338379011084.xls
After these changes the above modified URL is passed in the place of actual URL and when it hits the server it was decoded properly and worked as expected.